# Is there a way to make "find my iPhone" not work?

Tags: iphone

Is there any possible way to disable find my iPhone without just turning it off?

My parents are extremely clingy (in a very bad way) but luckily I am at least privileged enough to have my own iPhone.

Every once in a while my parents use the "find my iPhone" app when they're nosing even though they promised to only use it in emergencies.

I'll be grounded if I turn it off, but they wouldn't know if there was somehow a way to just say "iPhone cannot be found" or something. Perhaps if I jailbreak it?

Comment: Hello Jenny, please edit the question to fit the format we use here. Most of the information you are giving us has nothing to do with the actual problem and may cause people to read over it. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more info about asking questions

Comment: The solution to the problem is not about turning off Find my iPhone, it's about changing the password to your appleid.  http://appleid.apple.com and click manage. Don't forget to change the security questions and anything else that would help them reset the password.

Comment: @Tyson Please can you add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @GrahamMiln Even tho it is the best answer, it doesn't answer the question asked. Also I'm sure she's not allowed to change her password xD.

Answer (score 1):

### Remove an iOS device or Mac by turning off Find My iPhone

Remove a device from Find My iPhone by turning off Find My iPhone on the device.

On an iOS device: Go to Settings > iCloud, then tap to turn off Find My [device].

Note:   You can also remove your device by turning off iCloud completely on that device. Turning off iCloud turns off all iCloud features on the device.

You can read Apple's full article for more details, [iCloud: Remove your device from Find My iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is jailbreak your iphone and download fake gps you can put a fake location anywhere you want on the map and they will see that while you are some where else

Comment: Could you provide detail on how you might go about doing this exactly? Answers that only provide a superficial amount of guidance, such as this is in its current form, tend to attract down votes.

Answer (score -1):

Put the phone in airplane mode and only turn that off when you actually want to use it. That will at least cut down a lot on the time when you can be found, although of course you won't be able to receive incoming calls or texts, or push notifications.

Comment: that's the same as turning the phone off